# Radiobutton no es accesible debido a su nivel de protección

Tags: c#

Obtengo el siguiente error: Radiobutton no es accesible debido a su nivel de protección
Comparto con vosotros una captura a ver si sabeis a que se debe..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo marcar las respuestas correctas a tus preguntas? [click aquí para ver la imagen](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u7AxO.png)

Answer (score 3):

El problema es seguramente debido al nivel de acceso de tus `RadioButton` cambia a **[internal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx)** que significa accesible únicamente dentro de los archivos en el mismo ensamblado o **[public](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx)** en el cual define que no existen restricciones y se puede acceder desde cualquier ensamblado. El problema es que probablemente los tienes definidos como **[protected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx)** o **[private](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la documentación puedes ver un ejemplo:

> Se declaran dos clases, PointTest y MainClass.  El acceso a los
>   miembros públicos x e y de PointTest se realiza directamente desde
>   MainClass.

```
class PointTest
{
    public int x; 
    public int y;
}

class MainClass4
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        PointTest p = new PointTest();
        // Direct access to public members:
        p.x = 10;
        p.y = 15;
        Console.WriteLine("x = {0}, y = {1}", p.x, p.y); 
    }
}
// Output: x = 10, y = 15
```

> Si se cambia el nivel de acceso de public a private o protected, se
>   aparecerá el siguiente mensaje de error: 'PointTest.y' **no es accesible
>   debido a su nivel de protección.**

Comment: Muchas gracias excelente explicacion

Answer (score 3):

Por defecto el modificador de acceso de los controles es Private, lo que implica que solo es accesible en la clase que se encuentra declarado el elemento.
Para modificarlo, en el editor de interfaz de Windows Forms, te vas a las propiedades del RadioButton, y buscas la propiedad **`Modifiers`** y la estableces en **`Internal`** (accesible a nivel de ensamblado) o **`Public`** (accesible desde cualquier ensamblado). Con eso ya no debería presentar el error que mencionas.

Aquí dejo una captura de ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias eres un genio soy un poco nuevo en esto.. disculpa por las molestias

Comment: @OmarAlami Si alguna de las respuestas resolvió tu problema, considera aceptarla haciendo click en el **✓** a la izquierda de la respuesta (ambos se benefician). Más información en: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Y si alguna de ellas te fue útil, vota a favor haciendo click en la flecha hacia arriba.